# PHP/HTML : my forms do not work properly in Mozilla

Tags: php, html, forms, firefox, authentication

I have a rather "silly" problem with my login form.

It's a very simple and basic login form, which asks for **Username** and **Password**, and then is submitted when the user clicks the "submit" button.

```
  <form id="myform" action="login.php" method="post">
  Username : <input type="text" name="username" minlength="4" required/>
  Password : <input type="password" name="password" minlength="8" required    
  />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log In"/>
```

The problem I am having is with **Mozilla Firefox browser**.

My form works with **EVERY** browser out there : Chrome, Safari, IE, etc

When I open the form in other browsers, the cursor is blinking in the "Username" field, of course. As it should be.

But, when I open this form in Mozilla, there is no cursor blinking. I cannot write anything in the username or password fields.  (It is as though the fields are **READ-ONLY**)

But, when I click on the "**Log In**" button, then an error-alert message pops up, saying :  "**Username is a required field**" (obviously).

Then --- **and only then** --- the cursor finally appears in the Username text-box, and I am able to provide the login credentials.

I find this rather amusing. But, it certainly won't be amusing to someone who is using Mozilla Firefox!

What could the problem be?

I know there is nothing wrong with my code, because the form works in ALL browsers.  It even works in Mozilla, too...........but only **AFTER** I have clicked on the "submit" button, and then I am prompted to input the login credentials.

**UPDATE**

I finally found the cause of this problem!

One word :  "Javascript"!

As weird and downright ludicrous as this seems, the reason why my forms are behaving this way is because :  Javascript is ENABLED.

Once I disable Javascript in Mozilla, the forms work perfectly!

(And, it's not just my LOGIN form. It's every form in my website :  login, registration, selection, drop-down menus, etc)

To call this "ludicrous" is an understatement.  Why would any browser work properly only if JS was disabled ??  Almost 100% of anything done on the web these days requires that JS be enabled !

I don't even know how to begin to address this problem.

Should I paste a warning on my website, telling my users about this, and letting them know that : to use any of my website's forms in Mozilla, they need to first click on ANY random button (to get the form to "wake-up" from it's **Javascript-induced coma ??**"

**UPDATE**

I noticed somewhere online that someone else had a similar problem, when he tried to input his password into a form on Mozilla

Apparently he solved the problem by simply disabling Pop-up Blocker.

I tried that also.  And it did not work

I think that some JavaScript is running (on Mozilla) that prevents access to the input fields in my forms.

But, I dont know which, and I dont know WHERE  ((

Comment: have you close your form tag??

Comment: did you close the form tag?

Comment: Yes, I closed the <form> tag.  That is not the issue.

Comment: Anything in your browser's console? Can you provide a link to a live example (actual site or reproducible JSFiddle)?

Comment: cant provide the link to the live website.  I can however create an example in JSfiddle  (although I don't see how that will help.  The code itself works, as I said. And it's exactly as I wrote it up there).  Please, could you elaborate what you mean by  "in your browser's console" ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2xf5txm7/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same code , then there is no problem with your code of html.

```
<form id="myform" action="login.php" method="post">
 Username : <input type="text" name="username" minlength="4" required/>
Password : <input type="password" name="password" minlength="8"  required/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log In"/>
</form>
```

it might be a mozilla firefox cache problem try to clear it and restart browser and check it.It will work.

else check out for styles ,that might be causing a browser compatible issue.

Comment: Yes, this was my thought from the beginning.  I know the problem has NOTHING to do with my code.  And, I have cleared the browser cache a million times over  :=))     So, obviously, the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @phpnewbie2015 have you implemented any extra CSS styles for it ?

[ check this in firefox ](http://jsfiddle.net/axb8yesg/2/)

Comment: No.  There are no extra styling of any sort